# Can I be sure that files copied from a DVD are not corrupted?

Tags: windows-7, backup, dvd

I'm about to move a lot (like 100) of old backups made on DVDs to my new NAS.
The procedure I will use is simply: put a DVD in my Windows 7 PC, move its content to the NAS, repeat with next DVD.

If Windows completes the copy without complain about CRC errors or any other error, can I be sure that the copied files are identical to those in the DVD?

Due to the quantity of files I can't check them one by one, in case windows not complaining is not enough, what would be the best way to do it?

**EDIT:**
I ended up using [this](http://corz.org/windows/software/checksum/) free tool to automate the calculation of the checksum of the files in the DVDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're not using the /V switch on the venerable ol' "copy" command, about the best thing to do would be to grab a tool that could compute a hash or checksum on the source file, and compute the same hash on the copied file. If they match, the files are true duplicates. Microsoft released an unsupported tool that does precisely this many moons ago, and it appears still to be available [here.](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841290)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction, I've found this free utility http://corz.org/windows/software/checksum/ that greatly simplify recursive checksum calculation for arbitrary complex directories structures